# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'string'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm making a program with a login page and this error came up when coding it: Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `byte[]` and `string`

Im not sure where to go with it or how to handle it. This is my section with the error:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter your username.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        textBox1.Focus();
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        using (DataEntities test = new DataEntities())
        {
            var query = from o in test.Users
                        where o.Username == textBox1.Text && o.Password == textBox2.Text
                        select o;
            if(query.SingleOrDefault() != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have been successfully logged in.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    //Add your code process login here
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your username or password is incorrect.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the type for o.Password field?

Answer (score 1):

if your username and password fields are byte arrays you could convert them to string before doing the comparison:

Encoding.ASCII.GetString(o.Username) == textBox1.Text

Comment: Coming from more of a Java background here:
Is it not necessary to use the .equals() method instead of the == operator?

Comment: @Ryan_L: _"Is it not necessary to use the .equals() method"_ -- C# is not Java. C# allows operator overloading, and the `System.String` class does in fact overload the `==` operator, making it equivalent to calling the `Equals()` method (C# not being Java, there also is no `equals()` method).

Comment: How do I convert them? Would I use the code provided? And if so, where would I put it?