# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'string' | EDITED

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(o.Username) == textBox1.Text
```

this was the code I was previously given to fix this problem. I'm not sure where to put it in my code. Please help!!

This is the section with the error:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter your username.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        textBox1.Focus();
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        using (DataEntities test = new DataEntities())
        {
            var query = from o in test.Users
                        where o.Username == textBox1.Text && o.Password == textBox2.Text
                        select o;
            if(query.SingleOrDefault() != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have been successfully logged in.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    //Add your code process login here
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your username or password is incorrect.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't repost [a question you've already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707289/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-byte-and-string) to edit it. Just click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47707289/edit) link on the post. This question should be deleted, and the other one edited to fix whatever problems exist with it.

Comment: `o.Password == textBox2.Text` -> you should be **hashing** user passwords, ideally with a salt. It should not be possible to simply do an equality check. If someone hacks your database, they've got all of your user details and their plaintext passwords.

Answer (score -2):

You're getting this error when you try to compile, right?

I think your problem actually is that you don't have quotes around your query.

This:

```
var query = from o in test.Users
where o.Username == textBox1.Text && o.Password == textBox2.text
select o;
```

Should be:

```
var query = "from o in test.Users" +
"where o.Username == textBox1.Text && o.Password == textBox2.text" + 
"select o";
```

query is a string, so you need to surround everything right of the = with quotes.  This tells the compiler that it's a string literal, not more code.

Comment: It's Linq, not an SQL query. Even if it was an SQL query, it isn't a valid one. You can learn about the Linq query syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations).